# Iterate over number in element name

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I would like to create a loop in XSLT that converts the following XML:

```
<PAYMENTS>
    <PAYMENT_BATCH_ID>987654321</PAYMENT_BATCH_ID>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER1_AMOUNT>123456789</PAYMENT_NUMBER1_AMOUNT>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER1_CURRENCY>EUR</PAYMENT_NUMBER1_CURRENCY>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER1_DATE>19700101</PAYMENT_NUMBER1_DATE>
    <PAYMENT_STRING1_DESCRIPTION>Description</PAYMENT_STRING1_DESCRIPTION>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER2_AMOUNT>123456789</PAYMENT_NUMBER2_AMOUNT>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER2_CURRENCY>GBP</PAYMENT_NUMBER2_CURRENCY>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER2_DATE>19700101</PAYMENT_NUMBER2_DATE>
    <PAYMENT_STRING2_DESCRIPTION>Description</PAYMENT_STRING2_DESCRIPTION>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBERn_AMOUNT>123456789</PAYMENT_NUMBERn_AMOUNT>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBERn_CURRENCY>CHF</PAYMENT_NUMBERn_CURRENCY>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBERn_DATE>19700101</PAYMENT_NUMBERn_DATE>
    <PAYMENT_STRINGn_DESCRIPTION>Description</PAYMENT_STRINGn_DESCRIPTION>
</PAYMENTS>
```

Into this XML:

```
<PAYMENTS>
    <PAYMENT>
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
        <AMOUNT>123456789</AMOUNT>
        <DATE>19700101</DATE>
    </PAYMENT>
    <PAYMENT>
        <CURRENCY>GBP</CURRENCY>
        <AMOUNT>123456789</AMOUNT>
        <DATE>19700101</DATE>
    </PAYMENT>
    <PAYMENT>
        <CURRENCY>CHF</CURRENCY>
        <AMOUNT>123456789</AMOUNT>
        <DATE>19700101</DATE>
    </PAYMENT>
</PAYMENTS>
```

Note that n can be any number, so you can have any number of payments. And I am using XSLT 2.0.

I was unable to find out how to iterate over number in element name.
Please help?

Cheers,

Tuno

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="PAYMENTS">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="replace(local-name(), '\D+', '')">
      <PAYMENT>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </PAYMENT>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PAYMENTS/*">
  <xsl:element name="{substring-after(substring-after(local-name(), '_'), '_')}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms

```
<PAYMENTS>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER1_CURRENCY>EUR</PAYMENT_NUMBER1_CURRENCY>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER1_AMOUNT>123456789</PAYMENT_NUMBER1_AMOUNT>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER1_DATE>19700101</PAYMENT_NUMBER1_DATE>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER2_CURRENCY>GBP</PAYMENT_NUMBER2_CURRENCY>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER2_AMOUNT>123456789</PAYMENT_NUMBER2_AMOUNT>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER2_DATE>19700101</PAYMENT_NUMBER2_DATE>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBERn_CURRENCY>CHF</PAYMENT_NUMBERn_CURRENCY>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBERn_AMOUNT>123456789</PAYMENT_NUMBERn_AMOUNT>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBERn_DATE>19700101</PAYMENT_NUMBERn_DATE>
</PAYMENTS>
```

into

```
<PAYMENTS>
   <PAYMENT>
      <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
      <AMOUNT>123456789</AMOUNT>
      <DATE>19700101</DATE>
   </PAYMENT>
   <PAYMENT>
      <CURRENCY>GBP</CURRENCY>
      <AMOUNT>123456789</AMOUNT>
      <DATE>19700101</DATE>
   </PAYMENT>
   <PAYMENT>
      <CURRENCY>CHF</CURRENCY>
      <AMOUNT>123456789</AMOUNT>
      <DATE>19700101</DATE>
   </PAYMENT>
</PAYMENTS>
```

If you don't want all elements and you want to change the order of elements in the output then you need to explicitly list them:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="PAYMENTS">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="* except PAYMENT_BATCH_ID" group-by="replace(local-name(), '\D+', '')">
      <PAYMENT>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::*[contains(local-name(), 'CURRENCY')]],
                                     current-group()[self::*[contains(local-name(), 'AMOUNT')]],
                                     current-group()[self::*[contains(local-name(), 'DATE')]]"/>
      </PAYMENT>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PAYMENTS/*">
  <xsl:element name="{substring-after(substring-after(local-name(), '_'), '_')}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With that stylesheet and the input

```
<PAYMENTS>
    <PAYMENT_BATCH_ID>987654321</PAYMENT_BATCH_ID>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER1_AMOUNT>123456789</PAYMENT_NUMBER1_AMOUNT>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER1_CURRENCY>EUR</PAYMENT_NUMBER1_CURRENCY>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER1_DATE>19700101</PAYMENT_NUMBER1_DATE>
    <PAYMENT_STRING1_DESCRIPTION>Description</PAYMENT_STRING1_DESCRIPTION>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER2_AMOUNT>123456789</PAYMENT_NUMBER2_AMOUNT>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER2_CURRENCY>GBP</PAYMENT_NUMBER2_CURRENCY>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBER2_DATE>19700101</PAYMENT_NUMBER2_DATE>
    <PAYMENT_STRING2_DESCRIPTION>Description</PAYMENT_STRING2_DESCRIPTION>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBERn_AMOUNT>123456789</PAYMENT_NUMBERn_AMOUNT>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBERn_CURRENCY>CHF</PAYMENT_NUMBERn_CURRENCY>
    <PAYMENT_NUMBERn_DATE>19700101</PAYMENT_NUMBERn_DATE>
    <PAYMENT_STRINGn_DESCRIPTION>Description</PAYMENT_STRINGn_DESCRIPTION>
</PAYMENTS>
```

Saxon 9.5 outputs

```
<PAYMENTS>
   <PAYMENT>
      <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
      <AMOUNT>123456789</AMOUNT>
      <DATE>19700101</DATE>
   </PAYMENT>
   <PAYMENT>
      <CURRENCY>GBP</CURRENCY>
      <AMOUNT>123456789</AMOUNT>
      <DATE>19700101</DATE>
   </PAYMENT>
   <PAYMENT>
      <CURRENCY>CHF</CURRENCY>
      <AMOUNT>123456789</AMOUNT>
      <DATE>19700101</DATE>
   </PAYMENT>
</PAYMENTS>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your reply. For a great part this is what I am looking for. However I have edited the issue. The order of elements have changed and one element added. I need to have more control ignoring the first element. And grouping should be done on NUMBERn where n is sequence in loop. I should also be able to select currency, amount and date by element name.

Comment: @Tuno, I have edited the code to implement your changed requirements. If you have further changes to the input or output I suggest you post a new question.